# iPhone App Submission requires 5.5 inch display screenshots, but Xcode does not offer any simulators for these devices

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-simulator, retina-display

I am trying to submit an iPhone app to the App Store on App Store Connect but I am getting an error that says "You must upload a screenshot for 5.5-inch iPhone displays."

However, I am using Xcode 14.3 and it does not have any simulators with 5.5 inch devices. How am I supposed to get a 5.5 inch display screenshot? Is there a way to resolve this in App Store Connect?

Note: I have read that only the largest display sizes are needed, but I uploaded 6.7 inch display screenshots and it still demands 5.5 inch display screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer on the web. Go to "Devices and Simulators" under the Window tab and then click the + button to add the iPhone 8 Plus simulator.

Comment: This information is relevant only if your target is not iOS 17. However, if your aim is iOS 17, you may encounter limitations as the iOS 17 runtime is unavailable for any of the 5.5" devices, including iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, and iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: What is the solution if your app only supports iOS 17 and you can't run it on an iPhone 8 Plus simulator?

Comment: In xCode - Settings - Platform: Click + to add iOS15 Simulator. Then you will be able to get the correct screen size for iPhone 8 plus

Answer (score 0):

I used iPhone 8 Plus simulator with OS version 16.4, and the screenshots were accepted, but not with OS Version 16.0.